# Munkres: Connected Sets in the Real Line

Tags: general-topology

On page 154 Munkres proves the Intermediate Value Theorem and there is one part that I am unclear of.

He constructs the two set $A=f(X) \cap (-\infty,r)$ and $B=f(X) \cap (r,+ \infty)$

This statement: "If there were no point $c$ of $X$ such that $f(c)=r$, then $f(X)$ would be the union of this two above sets which are a separation of the image which is a contradiction.

My only comment: I see $A \cup B = f(X) \cap (- \infty, + \infty) = f(X)$, so if this $"c"$ does exist we would have say, $f(X) \cap (- \infty, r)$ = interval containing $"r"$, but this would mean $B=\{r\}$, which is not open, again contradiction the assumption of $A,B$ ? What I am trying to say here is that $f$ maps the set $X$ onto some open interval and if we assume something about the intersection of the image of $X$ under$f$, we will get a contradiction showing that the sets aren't in fact open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement is not correct $ A \cup B = f(X)\backslash \{r\}$ by construction $r$ is not in A and $r$ is not in B even if it were in $f(X)$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this cleared things up.

Answer (score 0):

No. You do not have f(X) intersects (-infinity,r) containing r !!!! Should be careful there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help.